# 'TypeNotRegisteredException' occurs when I try to use 'IUICompositionService' interface

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, catel

I have 'TypeNotRegisteredException' when I use 'IUICompositionService' interface in my WPF MVVM Catel application. Below I show how I try to use it. I'm in need of visualizing of 'CalibrationView' view in application MainWindow. To do it I've created a button 'btnShowCalibrationView' in MainWindow of my application, please see XAML below:

```
<catel:Window x:Class="FlowmeterConfigurator.Views.MainWindow"
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
          xmlns:catel="http://catel.codeplex.com"
          ResizeMode="CanResize">

    <catel:StackGrid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <catel:StackGrid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </catel:StackGrid.RowDefinitions>

        <ToolBar>
            <Button Name="btnShowCalibrationView" Content="Flowmeter Calibration" Command="{Binding ShowCalibrationView}"/>
        </ToolBar>
    </catel:StackGrid>

</catel:Window>
```

As you see from XAML above this button is binded to 'ShowCalibrationView' command. This command is in MainWindowViewModel.

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        // Create 'ShowCalibrationView' command.
        ShowCalibrationView = new Command(ShowCalibrationViewExecute, ShowCalibrationViewCanExecute);
    }

    // Declare 'ShowCalibrationView' command. 
    public Command ShowCalibrationView { get; private set; }

    // The command is always allowed to executing.
    private bool ShowCalibrationViewCanExecute()
    {
        return true;
    }

    // Here is the command logic for visualizing CalibrationView in MainWindow.
    private void ShowCalibrationViewExecute()
    {
        var viewModel = new CalibrationViewModel();
        var dependencyResolver = this.GetDependencyResolver();
        var uiCompositionService = dependencyResolver.Resolve<IUICompositionService>(); // The error is here!
        uiCompositionService.Activate(viewModel, "MainRegion");
    }
    . . . . . .
}
```

CalibrationViewModel is in the same 'ViewModels' folder as MainWindowViewModel in the application and 'CalibrationView' is in the same 'Views' folder as MainWindow in application (MainWindow is catel:Window and CalibrationView is catel:UserControl). When I try to execute ShowCalibrationView command then in line of code

```
var uiCompositionService = dependencyResolver.Resolve<IUICompositionService>();
```

the following error has place:
 *The specified type 'Catel.Services.IUICompositionService' is not registered or could not be constructed. Please register type before using it. The type 'Catel.Services.IUICompositionService' is not registered.* I have delay in development of my app due to this error. What I'm doing wrong? Please help me eliminate this error.

**P.S.** I've also tryed to add Bootstrapper class in my application and define the following code there as in https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Catel.Extensions.Prism#Catel.Extensions.Prism-Activatingaviewintoaspecificregion is shown:

```
public class Bootstrapper:BootstrapperBase<MainWindow>
{
    protected override void ConfigureContainer()
    {
        base.ConfigureContainer();

        if (ServiceLocator.Instance.IsExternalContainerSupported(this.Container))
        {
            ServiceLocator.Instance.RegisterExternalContainer(this.Container);
        }
    }
}
```

but  ConfigureContainer method has following error: *'Service locator' does not contain definition for 'Instance'*.

Answer (score 0):

Catel automatically registers the types *as soon as the assemblies get loaded*. But for an assembly to load in .NET, you need to reference at least 1 (non-interface) type in your code, like this:

```
var name = typeof(UICompositionService).FullName;
```

Another way is to use the [LoadAssembliesOnStartup Fody plugin](https://github.com/Fody/LoadAssembliesOnStartup), which does this automatically for you.

Comment: Thanks. But if I use Automatically Requesting Types Using Conventions then where in my application I should write next code: 'var serviceLocator = new ServiceLocator(); serviceLocator.RegisterTypesUsingDefaultNamingConvention();' ?